# How can I convert a NSString representation of a time value into two NSInteger's containing the hour and minute?

Tags: iphone, string, ipad, nsstring, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and the Objective C language and am building an alarm clock app to become familiar with the SDK and language.  I have an `NSString` object that represents a time, with the range `"1:00 am"` to `"12:59 am"`.  I need to convert this `NSString` into two `NSInteger`'s that contain the hour value and minute value.  As I'm doing this, I'm finding the `NSString` manipulation that I'm doing to be extremely laborious and it just feels like sloppy code.

Is there a simple way to extract the hour and minute characters from a `NSString` representation of a time value and store their numerical values in two `NSInteger`'s?

Thanks in advance for all your help!  I'm gonna get back to it...

Comment: Consider representing your time internally in a fashion that is more amenable to being inspected, and only generating strings like the ones you describe as output, rather than internal representations.

Comment: Will do, Seamus, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSScanner* timeScanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:...the time string...];
int hours,minutes;
[timeScanner scanInt:&hours];
[timeScanner scanString:@":" intoString:nil]; //jump over :
[timeScanner scanInt:&minutes];

NSLog(@"hours:%d minutes:%d",hours,minutes);
```

Comment: 6 years in iOS development, and I just discovered `NSScanner`. Very useful!

Answer (score 3):

1. Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your string into an `NSDate`.
2. Use the [`[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-SW4) to [extract](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-BBCCAFIG) various [date components](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents) (like the hour, minute, etc).

In other words:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:m a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"12:59 pm"];
[formatter release];

NSDateComponents * components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"hour: %d", [components hour]);
NSLog(@"minute: %d", [components minute]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the official way, as I know it. It's not pretty:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:m a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12:34 am"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h"];
NSString *hours = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"m"];
NSString *minutes = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

BUT the string fiddling way of doing it (look for `:`, look for space, ...), may give you more headaches on the long term.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *time = @"1:00 am";
NSString *removeam = [time stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" am" withString:@""];
SString *removepm = [removeam stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@" pm" withString:@""];   
NSArray *timeArray = [removepm componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger *hour = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSInteger *mins = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

Comment: thanks, i actually learned a lot about string manipulation from your example!

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an alarm clock app, you probably will want to look into the [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter) classes, instead of trying to pull all those strings apart into integer types.  Also, your time range is a bit weird (maybe a typo?) - don't you want all 24 hours to be available?

Answer (score 1):

get the time interval and write it as

```
duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)audioPlayer.duration / 60, (int)audioPlayer.duration % 60, nil];
```