# how to store time in NSDate without date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have a timer in my app. When I click on exit buton then timer gets stop and stores value into the string in format of 01:15:55 . I have an array to store this string object.

What I want is , now I want to display these values by comparing to each other. So I think first I have to convert the string into the NSDate but I am having only time format and do not want to store date.

How can I accomplish this task ? any suggestion ?

EDITED : code

```
NSInteger secondsSinceStart = (NSInteger)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:sDate]; // sDate = when app get started 

myAppDelegate.seconds = secondsSinceStart % 60;
myAppDelegate.minutes = (secondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
myAppDelegate.hours = secondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
NSString *result = nil;

if (myAppDelegate.hours > 0) 
{
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", myAppDelegate.hours, myAppDelegate.minutes, myAppDelegate.seconds];
}
else 
{
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", myAppDelegate.minutes, myAppDelegate.seconds];        
}

NSString *tempDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d",[myAppDelegate hours],[myAppDelegate minutes],[mogsApp seconds]];
```

Now I want to convert tempDateString into the NSDate so I can compare with similar objects. Is it possible ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an `NSTimeInterval` might be more appropriate. This is just a floating-point value indicating a number of seconds (including fractional seconds). You can manually format a value like this into whatever string format you want with some simple division and remainder math. (`NSDate` will give you time intervals since a reference date or other dates if you want to use those to get the values.) You can store NSTimeIntervals as strings if necessary.

Comment: ya i got seconds,minutes and hours by simple division and remainder math. I am getting string like 0:0:9 now How can i convert this string into the NSDate so I can compare it ?

Comment: @Maulik: Use a [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the string and convert it to a NSTimeInterval (which is just a float, BTW). To get an idea on how this is done, see the question [How can I convert a NSString representation of a time value into two NSInteger's containing the hour and minute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432260/how-can-i-convert-a-nsstring-representation-of-a-time-value-into-two-nsintegers).

Comment: @darkDust : I just want to do reverse of that process. As I ready have seconds,min &hours. I want to know that can I convert that into the NSDate without inserting date ?

Comment: @Maulik: Don't use NSDate, use NSTimeInterval. `NSTimeInterval time1 = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;` If you really, really must use NSDate then I'd suggest creating a string with a fixed date part where you insert your times and let NSDate parse that, but it's more work and surely more error prone.

Comment: @DarkDust : is it possible to get time like stopwatch's lap by using NSTimeInterval ?

Comment: @Maulik: Of course, just save it into a dedicated variable. If you want to support several laps, use a NSArray and store `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myTimeInterval]` (remember that a time interval is just a float).

Comment: @Maulik Yes there are many sample app's available on github for the stopwatch. just find on google and you will get one.

Answer (score 2):

[`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is always a good choice when storing only parts of a date/time (or a timespan).

It also gives you easy access to time management methods via [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470). Then (unlike using `NSTimeInterval`), you don't have to set up any of the math yourself, and it will all automagically localize.