# Separate Time from NSDate format like string?

Tags: ios

I am having a Date String in this format "2012-09-06 04:57:00.000". I need to separate the time in that string in 04:57AM like that. help me out of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *timeStr =  [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

The above code is with ARC otherwise you need to release formatter like

```
formatter release
```

Comment: thanks.. how can i proceed for any date?  i'm having  previous date along with time. so i that case how can i retrieve from that date string

Comment: If you want to start from Date string you can use NSString methods (parsing or like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432260/how-can-i-convert-a-nsstring-representation-of-a-time-value-into-two-nsintegers) or you can convert your NSString date to NSDate first. How ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353081/nsstring-to-nsdate)